# error al utilizar require_once desde directorios de diferente nivel - require_once no such file or directory

Tags: php

tengo la siguiente estructura de directorios en mi servidor

[image: null]

buscar_cuenta.php

```
require_once ('../../objects/cliente.php');
```

iniciar_sesion.php

```
require_once('../objects/cliente.php');
```

registrar_cliente.php

```
require_once('../objects/cliente.php');
```

cliente.php

```
require_once('../resources/dbconexion.php');
```

Los scripts `iniciar_sesion.php` y `registrar.php` requieren del script `cliente.php` y el script `cliente.php` requiere de `dbconexion.php` y esto funcionan perfectamente, pero mi problema esta aqui, cuando el script `buscar_cuenta.php`(que esta en otro nivel de directorio) requiere de `cliente.php` funciona bien, pero cuando `cliente.php` requiere de `dbconexion.php` ahi me sale el error de que no se puede encontrar el directorio, y si muevo el script `buscar_cuenta.php` al mismo nivel que se encuentran iniciar_sesion y registrar_cliente funciona, al parecer es un problema que se esta dando debido que se esta llamando desde un nivel de directorio diferente, pero tampoco quiero tener todos mis scripts en una sola carpeta, quiero tenerlos organizados con subdirectorios, podrian ayudarme con esto, gracias.

Answer (score 1):

El problema es que al haber 'require' de diferentes niveles, se pierde la referencia.
Por ejemplo:
Si `a.php` requiere a `../classes/1/b.php`
Y si `b.php` requiere a `../../common/c.php`

En este caso `a.php` llama correctamente a `b.php`. Pero cuando `b.php` llama a `c.php`, se hace relativamente desde donde se encuentra `a.php` y se pierde la referencia.

Esto puedes resolverlo de varias formas, pero una forma fácil puede ser creando un archivo común de configuración (tipo `config.php` por ejemplo) donde defines una constante con la ruta absoluta de la raíz del sitio.

```
define('BASE_PATH', '/var/www/html/misitio.com/public_html');
```

Otra forma es que sea PHP quien calcule el valor de la raíz del sitio

```
define('BASE_PATH', dirname(__FILE__));
```

Luego incluyes en tus archivos

a.php

```
require_once BASE_PATH . '/classes/1/b.php';
```

b.php

```
require_once BASE_PATH . '/common/c.php';
```