# ¿Por qué php no reconoce ruta de include?

Tags: php, mysql

¿que tal?. Tengo un problema con mi código en el include que llama a la conexion de base de datos, al intentar guardar, editar y eliminar, me lanza el siguiente mensaje:

> "Warning: include(Db/db.php): failed to open stream: No such file or
>   directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\taller1phpAvanzado\Controller\save.php"

Pero resulta que esa sí es la ruta y el index lo corrobora, ya que en él manejo la misma llamada para llenar una tabla con los datos traídos de mysql. Así tengo mi estructura, ¿En qué puedo estar fallando?, de antemano gracias.

Los siguientes codigos interactuan con las demás clases desde el index, en dichas interacciones es donde arroja el error:

```
    <form action="Controller/save.php" method="POST">
               <div class="form-group">
                  <input type="text" name="title" class="form-control" placeholder="Titulo" autofocus>
              </div>
              <div class="form-group">
              <textarea name="description" rows="2" class="form-control" placeholder="Descripción"></textarea>
              </div>
              <input type="submit" class="btn btn-success btn-block"
              name="save" value="Guardar">
            </form>
<script>
<td> <a href="Controller/edit.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>">
         <i class='fas fa-edit' style='font-size:30px'></i>
         </a> <a href="Controller/delete.php?id=<?php echo $row['id']?>"><i class='fas fa-trash' style='font-size:30px'></i></a></td>
</script>
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: por favor añade el código, así será mas fácil ayudarte

Comment: Desde que archivo le haces el include y cual es el archivo que ejecutas?

Comment: desde el index abro el archivo y llamo a Db/db.php, desde el index (aquí no pasa nada), y lo llamo con el include en el guardar, insertar y eliminar, los cuales al estar dentro de una carpeta me generan errores con el include, cosa que no pasa al estar dentro de una carpeta, ya qué me genera el error

Comment: Puede ser que tengas un problema de "ambigüedad de rutas". Eso sucede tipicamente cuando un archivo requiere a otro, que a su vez requiere a otros archivos, en directorios de diferente nivel. Observa esta respuesta https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270675/error-al-utilizar-require-once-desde-directorios-de-diferente-nivel-require-on/270692#270692

Answer (score 3, accepted):

El error te esta diciendo que en el archivo `Controller/save.php` estas haciendo un include del archivo `Db/db.php`.

Dado que no parece que utilices un bootloader ni namespaces en tu proyecto, entonces el problema está relacionado con las rutas del archivo. Estas utilizando rutas dinamicas, por lo que, si haces un include en un archivo (sin utilizar relativos como .. o .) se entiende que el include buscara DESDE el directorio en el que te encuentres.

Por lo tanto, el include de `Db/db.php`, que lo estas haciendo en el directorio `Controller` espera que exista el archivo `Controller/Db/db.php`, lo cual en tu proyecto es incorrecto.

Para solucionarlo, puedes cambiar el include a:

```
`../Db/db.php`
```

Lo que estas haciendo aqui es hacer referencia al directorio padre (de Controller) y luego al directorio `Db`, por lo que ahi encontrarás tu archivo.