# incluir con php un archivo correctamente sin problemas de directorios

Tags: php, html, html5

Antes de nada aclarar que no tengo mucha experiencia en php por lo que disculpas anticipadas por lo que probablemente sea una duda tonta, estoy justamente aprendiendo pero no he encontrado mucha información sobre esto en concreto

Estoy intentando importar desde un archivo que está en la ruta relativa del sitio:

`./blog/index.php`

realizo la importación con php de la siguiente manera:

`<?php require_once("../header.php");?>`

desde este archivo llamo al hearder que está en:

`./header.php`

este archivo **(header.php)** tiene una parte de **html** que muestra una imagen:

`<img class="col-2" src="img/logo/logo.jpg">`

desde el directorio raíz se muestra todo perfectamente, sin embargo cuando cargo desde el navegador **/blog/index.php** la imagen del logo no la encuentra, mirando la consola de mi navegador parece ser que está añadiendo el **root path** del sitio de la ruta que estoy cargando:

```
/blog/img/logo/logo.jpg
```

los **logs** de **nginx** me confirman lo ya mencionado

actualmente estoy desarollando en mi ordenador local con:

```
nginx 1.14.2
php7.3-fpm 
bajo debian 9
```

Gracias de antemano

Saludos,

Comment: Es un tema que se ha tratado otras veces. El problema es que al llamar archivos desde diferentes niveles, crea una ambigüedad de rutas respecto a donde se está ejecutando el script. Mira esta respuesta [error al utilizar require_once desde directorios de diferente nivel - require_once no such file or directory](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270675/error-al-utilizar-require-once-desde-directorios-de-diferente-nivel-require-on/270692#270692)

Comment: vaya, había probado ya con este método (poner la ruta absoluta) pero pensé que no era una solución muy correcta, Gracias!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

te recomiendo utilizar `$_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]`, podrias guardarlo en una variable de esta forma: `$dirpath = $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/blog/";`

o podrias hacer una funcion para devolver la ruta exacta como a continuacion:

```
include dpath("header.php");
```

y la funcion seria

```
function dpath($dir){
 return $_SERVER["DOCUMENT_ROOT"]."/blog/".$dir;
}
```

y cada cosa que necesites llamar solo invocas `dpath("y aca lo que necesites llamar");`

espero te funcione suerte.