# Warning: include PHP

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

> Warning: include(../Modelo/login_modelo.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\AvisionV2\login.php on line 2
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '../Modelo/login_modelo.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\AvisionV2\login.php on line 2

```
<?php
include '../Modelo/login_modelo.php';
?>
<!doctype html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">

<?php
/*Incluimos la conexion a la base de datos*/
include '../DataBase/ConexionBD.php';
session_start();


/*'REQUEST_METHOD'
 Método de petición empleado para acceder a la página, por ejemplo 'GET', 
'HEAD', 'POST', 'PUT'.*/
if ($_SERVER["REQUEST_METHOD"] == "POST") {

$MiUsuario = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['usuario']);
$MiContrasena = mysqli_real_escape_string($conn, $_POST['contrasena']);

$query = "SELECT id_usuario FROM tb_usuario WHERE r_usuario = '$MiUsuario' AND r_contrasena = '$MiContrasena'";
$resultado = mysqli_query($conn, $query);
$fila = mysqli_fetch_array($resultado, MYSQLI_ASSOC);
/**$activo = $fila['id_usuario'];**/

$contar = mysqli_num_rows($resultado);

if ($contar == 1) {
    /**session_register("r_usuario");*/
    $_SESSION['login_usuario'] = $MiUsuario;
    $_SESSION['login_id'] = $IdUsuario;
    header("location: panel_index.php");
    /**header("location: mostrarcookie.php");*/
    }
    /**setcookie('nombre', $MiUsuario, time()+4800);*/
    }
```

Directorio

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

---

Si eso esta bien pero me marca error,el **login_modelo.php**

> Warning: include(../DataBase/ConexionBD.php): failed to open stream: No such file or directory in C:\xampp\htdocs\AvisionV2\Modelo\login_modelo.php on line 3
>
> Warning: include(): Failed opening '/DataBase/ConexionBD.php' for inclusion (include_path='C:\xampp\php\PEAR') in C:\xampp\htdocs\AvisionV2\Modelo\login_modelo.php on line 3

```
<?php
/*Incluimos la conexion a la base de datos*/
include '../DataBase/ConexionBD.php';
session_start();
```

Comment: Intenta quitar `..` en el include.

Comment: Posiblemente tu problema se deba a ambigüedad de rutas en los includes. Mira esta pregunta y su respectiva respuesta a ver si no corresponde con tu caso. [Error al utilizar require_once desde directorios de diferente nivel](https://es.stackoverflow.com/questions/270675/error-al-utilizar-require-once-desde-directorios-de-diferente-nivel-require-on)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

estas tratando de ir una carpeta atras:

```
<?php
include '../Modelo/login_modelo.php';
?>
```

si lo colocas asi te deberia funcionar:

```
<?php
include 'Modelo/login_modelo.php';
?>
```

Comment: Me da error pero hoy con el login_modelo.php

Comment: cual error te da pegalo aca.